# Simplify mini max python algorithm

Tags: python

I've written a mini max algorithm, which I would like to simplify.

I call the function like this:

```py
board.push(move)
score = minmax(board, depth, tree)
board.pop()
```

And the actual function:

```py
def minimax(board: chess.Board, depth: int, tree: MinMaxTree = None) -> int:
    if finished(board) or depth == 0:
        return evaluate(board)

    def push_minimax_pop(move: chess.Move): 
        board.push(move)
        score = minimax(board, depth - 1, tree)

        if tree:
            tree.add_move(board, move, score)

        board.pop()
        return score

    scores = [push_minimax_pop(move) for move in board.legal_moves]

    if board.turn is chess.WHITE:
        return max(scores)
    else:
        return min(scores)
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this code, but a similar one with mutal recursion instead of the inner function. Therfore there might be a bug in the code, but I think the idea is clear anyway

Basically I have used an inner function to push and pop the move and also visualize the result of the recursive call.

There are multiple things I don't like about this implementation:

1. The need to push / pop the move before the first call of minimax
2. This "save result, pop, then return" pattern in the function. I have that in a lot of other functions too. Which is more complex than just returning the result directly.
3. The "debug" code here. The MinMaxTree visualizes the algorithm. Not only makes it the production code more complex, it's also not efficient as it does the `if tree` line on every recursive call

My idea is to use some decorator magic to make this simpler:

```
@visualize
@restore_board
def minmax(board: chess.Board, nextMove: chess.Move, depth: int) -> int:
    board.push(nextMove)

    if finished(board) or depth == 0:
        return evaluate(board)

    scores = [minmax(board, move, depth -1) for move in board.legal_moves]

    if board.turn is chess.WHITE:
        return max(scores)
    else:
        return min(scores)
```

1. Don't pass the next board to the minmax, but let it do the push itself
2. Use a decorator, which always calls pop() on every return -> Should be doable I guess
3. Use some magic `visualize` decorator, which is somewhat able to do the previous stuff now
4. (Not in the code) Allow to dynamically attach that visualize decorator

I have no idea if that's possible or how I would do that. It's just a vision of how the cleanest version of the original code would look like I could think of.

Is this doable? How could I realize this? (Especially the visualize decorator part)
Or are there other ideas how to make my code better?

Comment: You should ask for review on a complete section of code you've actually tested, which does something on its own.